Warning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Type' of undefined
Im am writing this code in react native with expo but the problem is when I click the button its giving me an error Warning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Type' of undefined
here is the button:
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.menuItem, styles.activeMenu]} onPress={handleCameraScanIn}>
            <Icon name="chart-line" size={20} color="#fff" />
            <Text style={styles.menuText}>Live Overview</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

here is my CameraScanIn.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function CameraScan() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [cameraRef, setCameraRef] = useState(null);

  // Request camera permissions on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting camera permission...</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} ref={(ref) => setCameraRef(ref)} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
});

here is my package.json
{
  "name": "camerascanner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~4.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^7.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "expo": "^52.0.7",
    "expo-camera": "~16.0.5",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "^13.0.5",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.14.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.13",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.0"
  }
}

How can I solve this? so that when I clicked the button it will not show me that error I keep on struggling over this. It will be a nice if someone can help me with this thank you.

is the error in a function called handleCameraScanIn?

Where is your handleCameraScanIn function defined?

This is the function defined in the Dashboard Screen. The camera is not opening
const handleCameraScanIn = () => {
navigation.navigate('CameraScan');  // Navigate to CameraScan screen
};
